# Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject 'does not contain a definition for X prop

Tags: c#

I am trying to store the one property of my object in a variable and it gives me an error referring to my object does not have a definition for my property.

> Error: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'str'.

[image: image with compiler error]

This only happens within my project, if I do it within a separate compiler, everything runs correctly and it should be, but I don't understand why I get this error in the project.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jf5xQf

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result you are receiving for JObject.Parse is of type JObject. To fetch the str value, you need to use

```
valorcito = d["str"];
```

You would be interested to read on [querying Json with Linq](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) with your current approach.

Comment: I just had to add the data type to your solution (string)valorcito["str"]. Thank you very much Anu!